# in app purchase error

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am getting this message repeatedly when using inapp purchase .it was working properly before 2 days .i have not changed any code.any idea on what may be the problem.....

```
 mycomputer-iPhone /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/Support/itunesstored[584] <Error>: URL: https://p24-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/offerAvailabilityAndInfoDialog?restrictionLevel=1000&guid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&quantity=1&offerName=xxxxxxxxxxxx&bvrs=1.0&bid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=en&icuLocale=en_IN Heuristics Failed, NOT PIPELINING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you releasing your request object?

This error is common if you release your request object too soon. If you are releasing it anywhere else but in the following method:

```
(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

then you are doing it wrong. See [this Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html) for more information.

Also make sure that you are signed out of the Store in the Settings application on your testing device before starting to test In App Purchase.

Comment: ya the second thing was the problem ...i signed out and from store in settings and then tried to use inapp purchase...it worked!!